# How to import and use feature vectors in MALLET's topic modelling?

Tags: lda, topic-modeling, mallet

- I am using MALLET's topic modelling.
- I have set of keywords along with weights for a set of documents which I want to train and use the model to infer new documents.

Note: each keyword of the document has weight assigned to it which is similar to tf-idf score.

Based on what I can infer from the documentation, MALLET's topic modelling **supports only sequence data and not vector data**.

I want to use the weights assigned to each keyword of the document for the analysis. If I don't then each keyword would be treated equally as a result I loose important information while analysing.

- Any suggestions of how I can use MALLET topic modelling for my data?

Comment: Hey can you explain how to set the keywords for training and the inference part?

Comment: Look at this question for a way to create documents from a feature vector that are ingestable by mallet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585075/using-topic-modeling-java-toolkit